# Return mysql result and use in another function

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a php function that gets a users ID based on their studentid.

```
function getID() {
    require "connect.php";

    $id = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT id, studentid FROM users
WHERE studentid = '".$_SESSION["studentid"]."'")  or die(mysqli_error($connection));


$userID = mysqli_fetch_assoc($id);
echo $userID['id']; // Just to make sure it works

}
```

I would like to use the result of this function in another function but dont know how.

I would specifically like to use it in a where clause , e.g:

```
WHERE id = getID());
```

Comment: First, this function needs to `return` something.

Comment: use `mysqli->prepare` to create a prepared statement

Comment: @JayBlanchard is correct; this function exposes nothing back to the caller. Please add that part so we can assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return $userID in you getId() function, and call the function when you build the query :

```
mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT id FROM table
WHERE id = '".getId()."'");
```